# keep getting /UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'comment' where it is not associated with a value' error

Tags: python, flask

not sure how to fix this...

**routes.py**

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, redirect, flash, request
from website import app, db
from website.models import User, Request, Comment
from website.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, RequestForm, CommentForm
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user

...

@app.route("/individual_requests/<int:request_id>", methods=['GET','POST'])
def individual_requests(request_id):
    request_and_user = db.session.query(Request, User).join(Request, Request.user_id == User.id).filter_by(id = request_id).first()
    form = CommentForm()
    if (request.method == "POST"):
     if form.validate_on_submit():
       comment = Comment(content=form.comment.data, request_id=request_id, user_id=current_user.id)
       db.session.add(comment)
       db.session.commit()
       flash('your comment was posted successfully, ' + current_user.username + '!')
       return redirect(f"/individual_requests/{request_id}")
    return render_template('individual_requests.html', request_and_user=request_and_user, form=form, comments=comment)
```

i tried changing `comments=comment` but nothing's worked. the comment's getting added to sqlite db but i want it to display on the page as well.

Comment: You only assign to `comment` if you enter both `if` blocks. What should `comment` be in the last return when `request.method == "POST"` or `form.validate_on_submit()` were `False`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (request.method == "POST"):
 if form.validate_on_submit():
   comment = Comment(content=form.comment.data, request_id=request_id, user_id=current_user.id)
```

The `comment` variable is only created when both of the `if` conditions are true.

But when one (or both) of them are false, `comments` never gets created.  Your code needs to handle that case.